# How To Create This Social Networking Buttons Expandable Bar

Tags: social-networking, addthis

I came across a social bookmarking expandable bar, seen on AddThis website http://www.addthis.com/social-plugins#.UaI8IEqJ23U (look at the bottom right of the page), for your convenience here is the screenshot :- [image: social bookmarking expandable bar]

Addthis doesn't provide this expandable bar and I want to know to create this bar or is there any website which provides similar bar like this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can get the expandable bar (it's called Peakaboo) - it's available in the AddThis Labs section:

http://www.addthis.com/labs/peekaboo-sharing#.UaYO_mRAR7Q